# Prove that if the limit of a real-valued function exists at a point, the function is bounded above

Tags: real-analysis, limits

> Let $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ and suppose that $\lim_{x\to a} f(x)$ exists. Prove that there exists a constant $M$ and a $\delta >0$ such that $|f(x)|<M$ for $0<|x-a|<\delta$.

Let's call this limit $q$. Since the limit exists, for all $\epsilon >0$, there exists a $\delta > 0 $ such that $0<|x-a|<\delta \Rightarrow |f(x)-q|<\epsilon$. I'm not sure how to go about showing boundedness, though.

Any hints would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $\epsilon = 1$, then $\exists \delta > 0$ such that if $0 < |x-a| < \delta$ then $|f(x) - L| < 1 \Rightarrow |f(x)| - |L| < |f(x)-L| < 1 \Rightarrow |f(x)| < 1+|L| = M$